# Sending email through ScreenFlow - problem adding threadId to template

Tags: email, email-template, email2case, screen-flow

I have created a ScreenFlow that's triggered with a button on a Custom Object (called Tech Issue).
When clicked, user can select multiple Cases amongst the Cases that are linked to said Tech Issue.

Then, another screen allows the user to type in a Subject and Body for the email they want to send to the Contact of the selected Cases.
I created a text template ressource that gets the Email Subject and Body from that screen.

My problem is that I would like each email being sent to include the threadId of the Case they "correspond" to. So that if the customer replies, the reply gets attached to the correct Case.

I have a loop in my flow where I tried to add the threadID to a collection but I either manage to send the same threadID to all selected Cases, or to send the full list of all threadIDs from selected Cases.

I'm adding screenshots of the Flow.
[image: ScreenFlow]

[image: Template ressource]
*Here I've tried with both the single threadID and threadID collection*

Any guidance or tips would be amazing!

Thanks
/Y